# How to append text to a column based on conditions?

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have an empty column designated for categorising entries in my data frame. Categories are not exclusive, i.e. one entry can have multiple categories.

```
         animals categories
1         monkey      
2 humpback whale      
3    river trout      
4        seagull
```

The `categories` column should have categories based on the animal's properties. I know the properties based on vectors. The elements in the vectors aren't necessarily a perfect match.

```
mammals <- c("whale", "monkey", "dog")
swimming <- c("whale", "trout", "dolphin")
```

How do I get the following result, ideally without looping?

```
         animals      categories
1         monkey          mammal     
2 humpback whale mammal,swimming     
3    river trout        swimming     
4        seagull
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be done with `fuzzyjoin` after creating a key/val dataset - `lst` from `dplyr` returns a named `list`, which is converted to a two column dataset with `enframe`, `unnest` the `list` column, grouped by 'animals', `paste` the 'categories' to a single string and then do a join (`regex_left_join`) with the original dataset

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)
keydat <- lst(mammals, swimming) %>%
     enframe(name = 'categories', value = 'animals') %>% 
     unnest(animals) %>%
     group_by(animals) %>% 
     summarise(categories = toString(categories))
regex_left_join(df1, keydat, by= 'animals', ignore_case = TRUE) %>% 
     transmute(animals = animals.x, categories)
# A tibble: 4 × 2
  animals        categories       
  <chr>          <chr>            
1 monkey         mammals          
2 humpback whale mammals, swimming
3 river trout    swimming         
4 seagull        <NA>
```

#### data

```
df1 <- tibble(animals = c('monkey', 'humpback whale', 'river trout', 'seagull'))
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you! Is there any way to make this case insensitive?

Comment: @szgfi add the `ignore_case` in `regex_left_join` (updated post)

Comment: awesome `regex_left_join` approach!

Comment: Thanks a million! It works.

Answer (score 0):

A base R option using `stack` + `aggregate` + `grepl`

```
lut <- aggregate(
  . ~ values,
  type.convert(
    stack(list(mammals = mammals, swimming = swimming)),
    as.is = TRUE
  ),
  toString
)
p <- sapply(
  lut$values,
  grepl,
  x = df$animals
)
df$categories <- lut$ind[replace(rowSums(p * col(p)), rowSums(p) == 0, NA)]
```

which gives

```
> df
         animals        categories
1         monkey           mammals
2 humpback whale mammals, swimming
3    river trout          swimming
4        seagull              <NA>
```

**Data**

```
df <- data.frame(animals = c("monkey", "humpback whale", "river trout", "seagull"))
```

Comment: I managed to get it to work with another answer, but thank you so much for replying!